# Drupal blocks - two javascripts which work independently as blocks don't work when placed on same page

Tags: javascript, drupal, block

my first ever scripts finally work independently as blocks on a drupal site.  Problem is, I need them to work in blocks side-by-side on the same page.  When I try this, only one of them works.  Have searched around to try to find the solution - all variables and elements are unique but there still seems to be conflict.  Here are the codes:

Block 1 code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 (function(){
    "use strict";
    window.getRisk = function()
{
    var size = window.document.getElementById('An_Size').value;
    var location = window.document.getElementById('locate').value;
    var ysah = window.document.getElementById('yessah');
    var nsah = window.document.getElementById('nosah');

    var x=size;
    var y=location;
        var z=ysah.checked?"yes":"no";

     if( x==0       ) output(" -- / --")
     if( x>0&& x<7      && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 1 /0 ")
     if( x>=7&& x<12    && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9948 /2.6 ")
     if( x>=12&&x<25    && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
     if( x>=25  && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.92 /40 ")
     if( x>0&& x<7          && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.995 /2.5 ")
     if( x>=7&& x<12    && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
     if( x>=12&&x<25    && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9632 /18.4 ")
     if( x>=25  && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9 /50 ")
     if( x>0&& x<7          && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 1 /0 ")
     if( x>=7&& x<12    && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 1 /0 ")
     if( x>=12&&x<25    && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.994 /3 ")
     if( x>=25  && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9872 /6.4 ")
     if( x>0&& x<7      && y=="ant" && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.997 /1.5 ")
     if( x>=7&& x<12    && y=="ant" && z=="yes" ) output(" 0.9948 /2.6 ")
     if( x>=12&&x<25    && y=="ant" && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
     if( x>=25  && y=="ant" && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.92 /40 ")
     if( x>0&& x<7      && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9932 /3.4 ")
     if( x>=7&& x<12    && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
     if( x>=12&&x<25    && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9632 /18.4 ")
     if( x>=25  && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9 /50")
     if( x>0&& x<7          && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 1 /0 ")
     if( x>7&& x<12     && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 1 /0 ")
     if( x>=12&&x<25    && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.994 /3 ")
     if( x>=25  && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9872 /6.4 ")

};

function output(str)
{
    var arr = str.split("/");
    var one_yr_risk = parseFloat(arr[0]);
    var life_expectancy = parseFloat(window.document.getElementById('life_expectancy').value);
    var cum_risk="--";
    var five_yr_risk="--"
    {
        five_yr_risk = arr[1];
        cum_risk = Math.round(((1-Math.pow((one_yr_risk), life_expectancy))*100)*10)/10;
    }
    window.document.getElementById('r2').value=five_yr_risk;    
    if(life_expectancy<10)
        cum_risk="--";

    if(cum_risk===0)
        cum_risk="0*";

    window.document.getElementById('r1').value=cum_risk;
    }
}());

      </script>

     <img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/COW.gif" style="width: 250px; height: 284px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px;" />
     <form action="" id="riskform" onSubmit="return false;">
     <fieldset>
     <label for="locate">Location</label>
     <select id="locate" name='locate'
     onchange="getRisk()">
    <option value="ant">Anterior circulation</option>
    <option value="post">Posterior circulation (incl. PCom)</option>
    <option value="int">Intracavernous</option>

    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
    <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>
    Size(mm)</label>
   <input type="text"  id="An_Size" size=7 onKeyUp="getRisk()"
   name="size" value="0"  />
   </p>
   <label >Previous SAH?</label>
   <input type="radio"  name="prevsah" value="yessah" id="yessah"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    Yes
    <input type="radio"  name="prevsah" value="nosah" id="nosah"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    No
   <br>
   <br>    
   <label for="Five_Year">5 Year Rupture Risk (%)</label>
   <input type="text" name="val3" id="r2"><span id="result2"></span>
      <p>
   <p>
   <br>
   <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>
    Estimated life expectancy (minimum 10 years)</label>
   <input type="text"  id="life_expectancy" size=7 onKeyUp="getRisk()"
   name="size" value="0"  />
   </p>

   <label for="One_Year">Cumulative Lifetime Rupture Risk (%)</label>
   <input type="text" name="val3" id="r1"><span id="result1"></span>

  <div id="Final_Risk"></div>

  </fieldset>
   </form>
```

Block 2 code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    "use strict";
     window.getRiskJp = function()
{
    var sizejp = window.document.getElementById('An_Size_Jp').value;
    var locationjp = window.document.getElementById('location_Jp').value;

    var a=sizejp;
    var b=locationjp;


         if( a<3        ) output(" -- / --")
         if( a>=3&& a<5     && b=="mca"     ) output(" 0.9977 /0.23 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="mca"     ) output(" 0.9969 /0.31 ")
         if( a>=7&& a<10    && b=="mca"     ) output(" 0.9844 /1.56")
         if( a>=10&& a<25   && b=="mca"     ) output(" 0.9589 /4.11 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="mca"   ) output(" 0.8313 /16.87")
         if( a>=3&& a<5         && b=="aca"     ) output(" 0.991 /0.90 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="aca"     ) output(" 0.9925 /0.75 ")
         if( a>=7&& a<10    && b=="aca"     ) output(" 0.9803 /1.97")
         if( a>=10&& a<25   && b=="aca"     ) output(" 0.9476 /5.24 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="aca"       ) output(" 0.6023 /39.77")
         if( a>=3&& a<5         && b=="ica"     ) output(" 0.9986 /0.14 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="ica"     ) output(" 1 /0 ")
         if( a>=7&&a<10     && b=="ica"     ) output(" 0.9881 /1.19")
         if( a>=10&&a<25    && b=="ica"     ) output(" 0.9893 /1.07 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="ica"       ) output(" 0.8939 /10.61")
         if( a>=3&& a<5         && b=="icapcomm"        ) output(" 0.9986 /0.41 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="icapcomm"        ) output(" 1 /1 ")
         if( a>=7&&a<10     && b=="icapcomm"        ) output(" 0.9881 /3.19")
         if( a>=10&&a<25    && b=="icapcomm"        ) output(" 0.9893 /6.12 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="icapcomm"      ) output(" 0 / around 100")
         if( a>=3&& a<5         && b=="bassca"      ) output(" 0.9977 /0.23 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="bassca"      ) output(" 0.9954 /0.46 ")
         if( a>=7&& a<10    && b=="bassca"      ) output(" 0.9903 /0.97 ")
         if( a>=10&& a<25   && b=="bassca"      ) output(" 0.9306 /6.94 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="bassca"        ) output(" 0 /around 100")
         if( a>=3&& a<5         && b=="vert"        ) output(" 1 /0 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="vert"        ) output(" 1 /0 ")
         if( a>=7&& a<10    && b=="vert"        ) output(" 1 /0 ")
         if( a>=10&& a<25   && b=="vert"        ) output(" 0.9651 /3.49 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="vert"      ) output(" 1 /0")
         if( a>=3&& a<5         && b=="other"       ) output(" 0.9922 /0.78 ")
         if( a>=5&& a<7     && b=="other"       ) output(" 0.9863 /1.37")
         if( a>=7&& a<10    && b=="other"       ) output(" 1 /0 ")
         if( a>=10&& a<25   && b=="other"       ) output(" 0.9719 /2.81 ")
         if( a>=25&& b=="other"     ) output(" 1 /0 ")

};

function output(str)
{
    var arrj = str.split("/");
    var one_br_risk = parseFloat(arrj[0]);
    var life_eapectancb = parseFloat(window.document.getElementById('life_eapectancb').value);
    var cum_riskj="--";
    var five_br_risk="--"
    {
        five_br_risk = arrj[1];
        cum_riskj = Math.round(((1-Math.pow((one_br_risk), life_eapectancb))*100)*10)/10;
    }
    window.document.getElementById('r2j').value=five_br_risk;   
    if(life_eapectancb<1)
        cum_riskj="--";

    if(cum_riskj===0)
        cum_riskj="0*";

    window.document.getElementById('r1j').value=cum_riskj;
    };
}());

       </script>

       <br>
       <form action="" id="riskformj" onSubmit="return false;">
       <fieldset>
       <label for="loc">Location</label>
       <select id="location_Jp" name='location_Jp'
       onchange="getRiskJp()">
       <option value="mca">Middle cerebral</option>
       <option value="aca">Anterior communicating</option>
       <option value="ica">Internal carotid</option>
       <option value="icapcomm">Internal carotid - posterior communicating</option>
       <option value="bassca">Basilar tip / superior cerebellar</option>
      <option value="vert">Vertebral / PICA / vertebrobasilar junction</option>
      <option value="other">Other location</option>

    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
    <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>
     Size(mm) (minimum 3mm)</label>
    <input type="text"  id="An_Size_Jp" size=7 onKeyUp="getRiskJp()"
    name="sizejp" value="0"  />   
   <p>
   <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>
    Life expectancy (minimum 1 year)</label>
    <input type="text"  id="life_eapectancb" size=7 onKeyUp="getRiskJp()"
    name="sizejp" value="0"  />
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
    <label for="Five_bear">1 year Rupture Risk (%)</label>
    <input type="text" name="val3jp" id="r2j"><span id="result2jp"></span>
      <p>
   <label for="One_bear">Cumulative Lifetime Rupture Risk (%)</label>
   <input type="text" name="val3jp" id="r1j"><span id="result1jp"></span>

    <div id="Final_Risk_Jp"></div>

  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: have you tried these in chrome with "use strict"; at the top of each function?

Comment: "use strict" breaks the code in Chrome and Firefox - doesn't work even with one block on page.

Comment: Did you see why it breaks it? That is probably what is causing your issue. If you hit F12 on windows it will open up the chrome developer tools and show you the error.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: both a and b are not defined in the second block which means they are implicit globals, looks like x and y have the same issue in the first block. I highly suggest running your code through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) in the future... it will help you catch things like this.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: that looks like a great tool!  Wish I'd found it earlier.  How can I properly define these variables?

Comment: just add `var` in front of the first instance of it

Comment: cool - if this works then you've finally put an end to days of faffing about

Comment: we haven't actually solved the problem yet... please update your examples above after you fix the errors

Comment: hmmm... now when on the same page values entered into the first cause changes in the second (see http://www.kockro.com/?q=en/node/36)

Comment: _function_ `output` is declared differently in each block, second will override definition of first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that you're not using closures around your code, this is important as any code not in a closure is global. As such right now both `output` functions exist... but which does the browser use... that is anyone's guess. A closure looks like this:

```
(function(){
 "use strict";
 window.getRisk = function(){ your code };
 function output() {your code };
 }());
(function(){
 "use strict";
 window.getRiskJp = function() { your code };
 function output(){ your code };
 }());
```

Please note that I am defining the functions that need to be visible outside the closure on the window object otherwise they will not be visible for callbacks.

Comment: updated script above - I'm sure I've taken something too literally here as have now broken both blocks

Comment: just noticed haven't closed output

Comment: does not appear you closed either output function, which would likely make both closures invalid just add a `}` before the end of the closure

Comment: it also appears you've put each output function in its own closure instead of the same closure with the function above it, remove the leading `(` in front of each output

Comment: You, sir, deserve several beers.